# Mobile & Tablet Device Testing

Tags: testing, mobile, cross-browser, tablet, mobile-devices

Can Somebody suggest me whether it is effective to Test all as many mobile device as possible to ensure a website compatibility.

As per my view, it is good for some extent to test various version of a Browser to check the Page view and compatibility rather testing many mobile or tablet devices.

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Your correct to some extend.When testing a mobile web site we need to be concerned about following

1. Browser compatibility
2. Page rendering in different screen resolutions/sizes

From above, we should pay more attention to Browser compatibility. And your correct on putting more weight on same.

By testing on many devices we can cover the screen resolution/form factor support.However, you should be able to create a good set of target test devices(Around 10)to cover the most used devices in the market.

For most used Android device types based on screen size, you can refer Android Dashboard for latest data 
https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

My suggestion based on current data, is to focus on following combination

1. Small Size - ldpi Density
2. Normal, Large, X Large - mdpi density
3. Normal Size - hdpi density
4. Normal Size - xhdpi & xxhdpi density

So for Android you can manage with around 7 devices for the initial round of testing based on current status

For iOS you could check the latest iPad & iPhone cause the platform has very few different screen sizes & adoption of the latest OS and device is better in iOS

Reference

http://www.fiksu.com/ipad-iphone-and-ios-7-adoption-trackers#ipad-usage
http://www.fiksu.com/ipad-iphone-and-ios-7-adoption-trackers#iphones-usage

Based on my experience with less than 10 devices you can have significant coverage on form factor support for mobile web testing.

Hope this is helpful..